# Issue with multiple calls using the jQuery Ajax load() method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the jQuery load() method to load content into a page depending on the value added into an input field. For some reason I am getting multiple ajax calls at once so the content I am calling is appearing twice in the page rather than just once.

Hope that makes sence!

Here is the code I am working on:

`function Acun () {
    var firstChar = $('#accountnumber').val().charAt(0);
    if(firstChar != 'x' && firstChar != 'X'){
         $('#examplepagecontent').html('<div id="invoice-loader"></div>');
         $("#examplepagecontent" ).load( "/product/pay-an-invoice #content");
    }
    else {
        $('#examplepagecontent').html('<div id="invoice-loader"></div>');
        $("#examplepagecontent").load("/product/pay-an-invoice-with-account-z #content");
    }
}`

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="Account Number" value=""  
  id="accountnumber" name="accountnumber" onKeyUp="Acun();" maxlength="7"/>
```

Comment: How are you calling the function Acun? do you have multiple times invoking this function by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function every keyUp. This means every time a character is entered with, when the button is lifted, the function will run.

You would want to try something like this

```
var timer;    //important to have variable outside the function
function Acun () {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        var firstChar = $('#accountnumber').val().charAt(0);
        if(firstChar != 'x' && firstChar != 'X'){
             $('#examplepagecontent').html('<div id="invoice-loader"></div>');
             $("#examplepagecontent" ).load( "/product/pay-an-invoice #content");
        }
        else {
            $('#examplepagecontent').html('<div id="invoice-loader"></div>');
            $("#examplepagecontent").load("/product/pay-an-invoice-with-account-z #content");
        }
    },500); //run after a half second of no activity
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried your code but the content is still appearing twice. I tried removing `onKeyUp="Acun();" ` from the input field and instead used the following button: `<button name="button" type="button" class="button" onclick="Acun();">Check</button>` but the issue still remains?

Comment: Maybe instead of using the html onclick attribute, try adding to your script outside of the Acun function somewhere `$('button[name="button"]').on('click',Acun);` If that doesn't work, is it possible that the click event is being applied twice somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `Acun()` function on `onKeyUp="Acun();"` event. This event happen each time the user presses the button.

You should check the other requests are pending, and do not request the new one, or you can check the length of `textbox` input, and make a request with largest one.